# Log4j logging performance

Tags: java, performance, logging, log4j

Log4j pattern layout [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) warns that generating caller class information is costly and should be used only when performance is not a concern. I want to have the class name in logs for easy analysis and also doesn't want to have an impact in performance. Having stated that I have two options,

1. Store class name using getClass().getName() in every class and use that string in logging

   `String class = getClass().getName();
   ...
   ...
   logger.debug(class + "log message");`
2. Hardcode the class name and give it in log

   `String class = "com.foo.myclass";
   ...
   ...
   logger.debug(class + "log message");`

Which would give better performance or is there any other way to log fully qualified class name and method name without affecting performance. Thanks in Advance!

Note: I am using log4j 1.2.16

Comment: Is there a reason you would want to log every class name in production environment? Why can't you just log caller class info on a say `TRACE` level when you need to perform the analysis, and use the `WARN` level or whatever on production environment when you need performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating the caller class name is costly but if you're following the typical Log4J design pattern of one `Logger` per class with the `Logger` name being the same as the class name

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ThisClassName.class);
```

then it may be sufficient to simply use `%c` instead of `%C` in your layout pattern.  This uses the logger name (which is a property of the logger itself) rather than inspecting the call stack, and does not involve the overhead incurred with patterns like `%C` or `%L`.

If you really do need the runtime class of the caller rather than the static name of the class that textually encloses a particular logging call, then you could use a per-instance logger rather than (or as well as) the per-class one

```
private final Logger instLog = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

and now the logger name will be the runtime type of `this`, i.e. if B extends A and we call a method on an instance of B then the logger name will be B, even for methods that are actually defined by the superclass A.

Answer (score 2):

A usual pattern for loging with log4j is the following

```
public class Foo {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class);

    someMethod(){
         ...
         if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()){
              LOG.debug("log message");
         }
    }
}
```

The classname is the logger name so it will (by default) appears in the log message.

Most importantly regarding performance: there is a guard preventing the overhead of the computation of the log message when the log level is not enabled.

Comment: This improves performance if logs áre disabled. Otherwise, it slows down logging.

Comment: slow down logging because of the additionnal test ? ... I think it's insignificant (and most of the time, in production : the log level is WARN or ERROR). Additionally with this solution you don't have to concat 2 strings to get the classname.